# LaTeX issue after compiling from Rd files

Tags: r, tex, rd

Apparently I've an issue after compiling few Rd files of an R package to LaTeX. It seems that `pdftex` cannot find Rd2 files to build the manual properly. The output is ok, but lacks the index. I'm running on a Macbook with 2013basic latex basic distribution with extra packages. Doe anybody have a tip to tell?

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 entering extended mode
 (./Rd2.tex
 LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
 Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/alltt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def))
No file Rd2.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pcr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
No file Rd2.toc.

.....

Output written on Rd2.pdf (44 pages, 210813 bytes).
Transcript written on Rd2.log.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Rd2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
```

Comment: It is probably related to https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067587.html

Comment: In order to get an index, you need to compile with (pdf)LaTeX, then "recompile" using `makeindex`, and then compile again with (pdf)LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by installing `texi2dvi` in the `texinfo` linux package.